# Passing parameters with different names and treating it as one

Tags: apex, visualforce, url, parameters

I have to pass language code from the URL to VFP/Apex Code, and the language parameter can be in two different name

> - lang
> - language

so it can be passed like

```
www.something.com?lang=en_US
```

or

```
www.something.com?language=en_US
```

and I have to get the parameter in `apex:page` tag and make the Apex Variable 'language' to be in sync with the URL parameter.
Please do comment if you want more description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also just use a conditional expression

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" language="{!Blankvalue($currentpage.parameters.lang, $currentpage.parameters.language) }">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @TariqueShamim You can also use BlankValue, which is shorter: `{!BLANKVALUE($CurrentPage.parameters.lang, $CurrentPage.parameters.language)}`

Comment: Updated answer to reflect sfdcfox recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet will be like this:

Take URLParameters in a map and loop through the map and retrieve the value.

**Controller**

```
public class MyController
{
    public String paramValue {get;set;}
    public MyController()
    {
        Map<String, String> paramMap = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        for(String str:paramMap.keyset())
        {
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase('lang') || str.equalsIgnoreCase('language'))
            {
                paramValue = paramMap.get(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

Now, use `language` attribute and `paramValue` from Controller property.

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" language="{!paramValue}">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `==` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase`, since they do the same thing, but one is much longer.